# SQL UPDATE or INSERT

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I have tried the different solutions that found on this site when it comes to update or insert using SQL code, I got the update working but can't implement a working insert if the rows doesn't exists, the (update) code that is working looks like this, any help on how to make it insert also would be nice since I'm an *SQL Newbie, well here is the working code:

```
select top 0 * into #tmp_x from TTT;
select * from #tmp_x;
BULK INSERT #tmp_x FROM 'path\to\file1.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR =';',ROWTERMINATOR ='\n' ,FIRSTROW = 2);
UPDATE TTT
SET TTT.[Artikelbenämning] = #tmp_x.[Artikelbenämning],TTT.[Count of Ordernummer] = #tmp_x.[Count of Ordernummer],TTT.[Sum of Antal beställda] = #tmp_x.[Sum of Antal beställda],TTT.[Min of Skapat Datum] = #tmp_x.[Min of Skapat Datum],TTT.[Max of Planerat Plockdatum] = #tmp_x.[Max of Planerat Plockdatum],TTT.[Kommentar Inköpsplanerare] = #tmp_x.[Kommentar Inköpsplanerare]
FROM #tmp_x
WHERE TTT.Artikelnummer = #tmp_x.Artikelnummer;
drop table #tmp_x;
print 'dropped table';
```

Comment: change that WHERE statement to an INNER JOIN, see if that works for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have SQL Server 2008 or later, you can make use of the MERGE statement. The following Microsoft TechNet article describes the merge statement pretty well:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522522(v=sql.105).aspx

Your query should look something like this:

```
    BULK INSERT #tmp_x FROM 'path\to\file1.csv' WITH (FIELDTERMINATOR =';',ROWTERMINATOR ='\n' ,FIRSTROW = 2);

    MERGE TTT AS T
    USING #tmp_x AS S
    ON (T.Artikelnummer = S.Artikelnummer) 
    WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
        THEN INSERT(
                     [Artikelnummer]
                    ,[Artikelbenämning]
                    ,[Count of Ordernummer]
                    ,[Sum of Antal beställda]
                    ,[Min of Skapat Datum]
                    ,[Max of Planerat Plockdatum]
                    ,[Kommentar Inköpsplanerare]
                    ) 
            VALUES( 
                     S.[Artikelnummer]
                    ,S.[Artikelbenämning]
                    ,S.[Count of Ordernummer]
                    ,S.[Sum of Antal beställda]
                    ,S.[Min of Skapat Datum]
                    ,S.[Max of Planerat Plockdatum]
                    ,S.[Kommentar Inköpsplanerare]
                  )
    WHEN MATCHED 
        THEN UPDATE 
            SET      T.[Artikelbenämning] = S.[Artikelbenämning]
                    ,T.[Count of Ordernummer] = S.[Count of Ordernummer]
                    ,T.[Sum of Antal beställda] =   S.[Sum of Antal beställda]
                    ,T.[Min of Skapat Datum] =  S.[Min of Skapat Datum]
                    ,T.[Max of Planerat Plockdatum] = S.[Max of Planerat Plockdatum]
                    ,T.[Kommentar Inköpsplanerare] =    S.[Kommentar Inköpsplanerare];

                ,T.[Kommentar Inköpsplanerare] =    ISNULL(S.[Kommentar Inköpsplanerare], T.[Kommentar Inköpsplanerare]);

-- Example exludes records where [Kommentar Inköpsplanerare] IS NULL from the merge
MERGE TTT AS T
USING (
        SELECT  
                 [Artikelnummer]
                ,[Artikelbenämning]
                ,[Count of Ordernummer]
                ,[Sum of Antal beställda]
                ,[Min of Skapat Datum]
                ,[Max of Planerat Plockdatum]
                ,[Kommentar Inköpsplanerare]
        FROM     #tmp_x 
        WHERE   [Kommentar Inköpsplanerare] IS NOT NULL
      )AS S
ON (T.Artikelnummer = S.Artikelnummer) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT(
                 [Artikelnummer]
                ,[Artikelbenämning]
                ,[Count of Ordernummer]
                ,[Sum of Antal beställda]
                ,[Min of Skapat Datum]
                ,[Max of Planerat Plockdatum]
                ,[Kommentar Inköpsplanerare]
                ) 
        VALUES( 
                 S.[Artikelnummer]
                ,S.[Artikelbenämning]
                ,S.[Count of Ordernummer]
                ,S.[Sum of Antal beställda]
                ,S.[Min of Skapat Datum]
                ,S.[Max of Planerat Plockdatum]
                ,S.[Kommentar Inköpsplanerare]
              )
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE 
        SET      T.[Artikelbenämning] = S.[Artikelbenämning]
                ,T.[Count of Ordernummer] = S.[Count of Ordernummer]
                ,T.[Sum of Antal beställda] =   S.[Sum of Antal beställda]
                ,T.[Min of Skapat Datum] =  S.[Min of Skapat Datum]
                ,T.[Max of Planerat Plockdatum] = S.[Max of Planerat Plockdatum]
                ,T.[Kommentar Inköpsplanerare] =    S.[Kommentar Inköpsplanerare];


-- Example ignores updates on the [Kommentar Inköpsplanerare] column if the [Kommentar Inköpsplanerare] IS NULL in the source dataset
MERGE TTT AS T
USING #tmp_x AS S
ON (T.Artikelnummer = S.Artikelnummer) 
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET 
    THEN INSERT(
                 [Artikelnummer]
                ,[Artikelbenämning]
                ,[Count of Ordernummer]
                ,[Sum of Antal beställda]
                ,[Min of Skapat Datum]
                ,[Max of Planerat Plockdatum]
                ,[Kommentar Inköpsplanerare]
                ) 
        VALUES( 
                 S.[Artikelnummer]
                ,S.[Artikelbenämning]
                ,S.[Count of Ordernummer]
                ,S.[Sum of Antal beställda]
                ,S.[Min of Skapat Datum]
                ,S.[Max of Planerat Plockdatum]
                ,S.[Kommentar Inköpsplanerare]
              )
WHEN MATCHED 
    THEN UPDATE 
        SET      T.[Artikelbenämning] = S.[Artikelbenämning]
                ,T.[Count of Ordernummer] = S.[Count of Ordernummer]
                ,T.[Sum of Antal beställda] =   S.[Sum of Antal beställda]
                ,T.[Min of Skapat Datum] =  S.[Min of Skapat Datum]
                ,T.[Max of Planerat Plockdatum] = S.[Max of Planerat Plockdatum]
                ,T.[Kommentar Inköpsplanerare] =    ISNULL(S.[Kommentar Inköpsplanerare], T.[Kommentar Inköpsplanerare]);
```

Comment: Worked Perfectly!
Thanx a billion :)

Comment: But how do i check if S.[Kommentar Inköpsplanerare] = null and prevent overwrite existing value in database? or is it not possible?

Comment: It depends what you want to do with NULL values. Example if you want to simply exclude records with NULL values from your source set then you can update your source table in the using clause with a query. I have updated the example to show how this will be done.
Alternativley if you simply want to ignore a specific field if the corresponding source field is null you can use the “ISNULL()” function to simply return the original value if the source is null.

Comment: Again your the king of sql :) the second example was exactly what i was trying to do and i was very close just missed a , haha :) BIG THANX AGAIN!!!

Answer (score 1):

In Sql server, you can do both insert and update in the same statement, called [`MERGE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx)

```
MERGE TTT AS target
USING #tmp_x AS source 
ON (target.Artikelnummer = source.Artikelnummer )
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
    UPDATE SET [Artikelbenämning] = source.[Artikelbenämning],
               [Count of Ordernummer] = source.[Count of Ordernummer],
               [Sum of Antal beställda] = source.[Sum of Antal beställda]....
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
INSERT (<target's columns list>) -- I got a little lazy here...
VALUES (<source's columns list>)
```

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to @Edmond Quinton would be to delete matching rows and insert after:

```
DELETE TTT
FROM TTT
INNER JOIN #tmp_x
ON TTT.Artikelnummer = #tmp_x.Artikelnummer

INSERT INTO TTT
SELECT * FROM #tmp_x
```

Comment: This is a bad idea. If TTT has tables connected to it with a foreign key constraint it might either raise an error or delete records from these tables (if on delete cascade is set to true).

Comment: that is correct, it all comes down to what data is used for and the dependencies. It seemed like a table for analyses (there are sums of orders and stuff that would never make it to production) and the delete, insert is the fastest option. Merge is 2008+ and slower specially when there are constraints. For professional purpose, you  would create an ETL process.